# can't solve this error with json object

Tags: java

i write this code to read json data , and there is an error when run the code

first this is the code i write ( i changed the code to correct the json string but the problem still exist )

```
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;

public class defaults {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jsonTxt = "{lhs: \"100 Euros\",rhs: \"128.551738 Australian dollars\",error: \"\",icc: true}";        
         JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( jsonTxt );
        String title = json.getString("title");               
        System.out.println( "title: " + title );
    }
}
```

and i have found this error when run the code

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableRuntimeException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source).....
```

the error gone away if i remove lines that talks about json

Comment: The error goes away because the JSON library you're using depends on Apache commons lang. If you're not using the library you don't need the dependency and thus you won't get the exception. Adding a library to the classpath is a basic skill you need to learn - it's going to come up time and time again unless you write everything from scratch.  I gave you a link to instructions on how to add a jar to the runtime classpath in Eclipse - please learn how to do this basic task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String jsonTxt = "{'lhs': '100 Euros','rhs':'128.551738 Australian dollars','error':'','icc': 'true'}";        
JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON( jsonTxt );
System.out.println( "lhs: " + json.getString("lhs") );
System.out.println( "rhs: " + json.getString("rhs") );
System.out.println( "error: " + json.getString("error") );
System.out.println( "icc: " + json.getString("icc") );
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
lhs: 100 Euros
rhs: 128.551738 Australian dollars
error: 
icc: true
```

you can give the json string with double quotes(") or single quotes(') or key without quotes. All works.

you need following jars:

```
1. commons-lang-2.4.jar
2. ezmorph-1.0.jar
3. json-lib-0.9.jar
```

for adding the jars through eclipse:

```
1.right click on project folder
2.click on prperties
3.select "java build path"
4.select libraries tab
5.click on "Add External jars"
6.Browse your jars, select and click ok.
```

Comment: updated the answer.. please check the 2nd point, most probably it will remove the exception.

Comment: it's not for web , it's windows application will run with java .

Comment: ooopppppsssss.. updated the steps, please follow that in eclipse

Comment: same error :( can u make the program in your computer and give it to me

Comment: well.. i have executed the code in my machine and updated the answer. please check it.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the [Apache Commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) library from your classpath.

If you ever are stumped by a `NoClassDefFoundError` try plugging the class name into [jarFinder](http://www.jarfinder.com/) - that will tell you jar files where the class can be found.

Comment: sorry how can i do this , iam on eclipse

Comment: I believe you look in Run -> Run Configuration, choose your application configuration, and ensure the jar file is on the classpath.

Comment: No matter which library you choose you still need to ensure all the dependencies are on the classpath. The problem is not with the library - I've used that library and it works very well. You need to learn how to set up your classpath in Eclipse.  Perhaps [this article](http://www.ehow.com/how_4784820_set-classpath-eclipse.html) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have a hanging "," after 'true'.

And technically strings and property names in JSON should use double quotes, not single quotes.

Comment: Those issues aren't the cause of his `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Comment: s/should/mush. A JSON parser *may* accept single quotes but chances are good that it *requires* double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You doesn't have [Apache commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) in your runtime classpath.